# Binding not working in Angular Tutorial example

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
<div ng-app="">
  <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
  <h1>{{ data.message }}</h1>

  <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
    <h1>{{ data.message }}</h1>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
    <h1>{{ data.message }}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the HTML code they had to demonstrate "Sharing Data Between Controllers" but the bindings inside FirstCtrl and SecondCtrl didn't work for me. Is this way of binding not included in Angular 1.3?

**Controllers**

```
function FirstCtrl($scope) {

}

function SecondCtrl($scope) {

}
```

[Original Tutorial Link](https://thinkster.io/egghead/sharing-data-between-controllers)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7d05jtLn/)

Comment: Post your code, that you produced. Then we can fix it

Comment: You should continue to read on that tutorial. The solution you have posted is only the first part, which they later state is not a good solution.

Comment: @Callum This is the code I produced too. The binding is fine for the model outside the contollers but the ones inside are not working. 
I am just trying to reproduce what they're teaching in the tutorial.

Comment: @Patrick, yeah I figured but it somehow worked for them then, right? I'm just asking why it isnt working for me.

Comment: Create plnkr and then post the link, that way I can *see* what you have done.

Comment: @Callum http://jsfiddle.net/7d05jtLn/

Comment: Your example is working, it's just that jsfiddle is..well..fiddly. Working example is here; http://jsfiddle.net/8zaxgwbc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of angular 1.3 you can no longer use global functions as controllers, you must explicitly add them to your module.

1. Name your module in your markup ng-app="my-app"
2. Create a module in code var app = angular.module('my-app', []);
3. Add your controllers to the module app.controller('FirstCtrl', FirstCtrl)
4. Enjoy data binding